# Find matches with one Regex compound by several Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Using C# I have a small set of 3 regular expressions:

1. `(?i)(<title.*?>)(.+?)(</title>)`
2. `(?i)ancyent (?=marinere)`
3. `[a-zA-Z]{12}`

And this small text:

```
<html lang="en"> <head> <title>The Rime of the Ancyent Marinere (1798)</title> </head> <body> <h1>THE RIME OF THE ANCYENT MARINEREEEEEEEE, IN SEVEN PARTS.</h1>
```

I get the matches with this code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(textFile, pattern.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Number of matches launching regexes individually: 4.

1. `<title>The Rime of the Ancyent Marinere (1798)</title>`
2. `Ancyent`
3. `ANCYENT`
4. `MARINEREEEEE`

But if I am trying to match writing the 3 regexes in a big one in this way,

```
((?i)(<title.*?>)(.+?)(</title>)|(?i)ancyent (?=marinere)|[a-zA-Z]{12})
```

Number of matches launching regex all in one: 3.

1. `<title>The Rime of the Ancyent Marinere (1798)</title>`
2. `ANCYENT`
3. `MARINEREEEEE`

My question is: Is there any possibility to get ALL the matches using one regular expression compound of several regex linked by the `|` operator?

Comment: The issue is confused, given the input shown, what is needed to be matched? You say `all matches` what does that mean exactly. For two of the matches shown are the same. It appears once you get the title information, it has all the info needed; hence one match could do it all.

Comment: Indeed.. the regex you provided *is* getting you ALL the matches in one regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: No, because a single regex will not match the same substring twice. The match marked 2 in your first list (`Ancyent`) is part of the same substring as the first match. Since the first match is matched by the first part of your compound regex, you get that match, and then the substring `Ancyent` has already been consumed and will not be matched by the second part of the compound regex.

Comment: Ok, Sean thanks. That make sense maybe there is no way to count again the match again once it was consumed.